# APDU Read Record ACR122

Tags: nfc, smartcard, acr122

I am trying to use a USB NFC card reader, ACR122U.

I managed to get the ID of the card by sending `0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00` and to tell the unit not to beep by sending control `0xFF, 0x00, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00`. However, using an Android app I wrote a URL to the cards first record (0).

Following the specs [here](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_6_basic_interindustry_commands.aspx#chap6_5), I should send `0xFF, 0xB2, 0x00, 0x08, 0x00` to read the first record, however I only get "c" as a response.

Does anyone have the actual command to send to get the first record?

Thanks!

Comment: try 0x00,0xB2,recordno,0x04,length to read data

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the .Transmit() method instead of the .Control() method.